# Adding photo to website profile page using Html

Tags: html

I am currently working on coding profile page for users on website and I want to enable user to upload his photo in a small frame but the idea is that I don’t have a variable for image on database that saves it each time , so is was wondering if there is such a way to let users upload photos on their profile and each time they log out and come back they find it again.
Thanks,

Comment: the simplest way is to just provide them the ability to give you a link to their image stored somewhere else and call that into an <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use userID to store images. Example , My userID is "132"

store images in profile_pic/132.jpg

When you need the picture , call it something like this.(sample in php)

```
 $userid=//get userid from database;
 $profilepic="profile_pic/".$userid.".jpg";

 //show it to the world!!!
```